# How to copy hidden (starting with a dot) files and subdirectories in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

How to copy hidden files and hidden subdirectories (the ones starting with a dot) in folder A to folder B? For example if I have this structure:

```
A/a
A/b
A/.a
A/.b/
A/.b/somefile
A/.b/.c
```

I would like to copy to B just the hidden files and hidden subdirectories in A:

```
B/.a
B/.b/
B/.b/somefile
B/.b/.c
```

I have already tried this command: `cp A/.* B` from [this other superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/265220/how-do-i-copy-file-named-starting-with-a-dot). However, it does not copy the subdirectories. Also tried `cp -r A/.* B`, but it copies `.` so I end with an exact copy of A (including the normal files). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As long as you're only looking for hidden files and folders at the level of A and don't want, for example

```
A/b/.hidden
```

to be copied, you should be able to use this:

```
cp -r A/.[^.]* B
```

It basically means copy anything that starts with a `.` and then any character other than a `.` That filters out `.` and `..`

Edit: Removed the -p from the cp command since Asker hasn't indicated he wants to preserve any ownerships, dates, etc.

Comment: This works for the _example_ file and directory names given in the question, but the text of the question says “hidden files and hidden subdirectories (the ones starting with a dot)”, and this answer will not find files and directories whose names begin with _two_ dots; e.g., `..c`.

Comment: That's quite an edge case, but a legitimate concern none-the-less. I hadn't considered that. You could account for that by switching to `.*[^.]` but then you'd miss files that end with a `.`. I think you would indeed need extended globbing to truly account for all cases.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `A/.*` is that there is the directory `.` in `A` which also matches the pattern.

You can turn on extended glob patterns and use the following:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r A/.!(?(.)) B
```

It matches files whose name starts with a dot and whose second character is neither a dot nor nothing ( ?(.) matches nothing or a dot, !(...) negates it, i.e. !(?(.)) matches everything else than nothing or a dot).

Comment: +1 for a correct answer. Note that `.!(@(|.))` is (AFAICT) equivalent to the above, (IMNSHO) a little clearer, and only one character longer.

Answer (score 5):

For cases like this would recommend using [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) instead of [`cp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp) like this:

```
find A/ -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -exec cp -p {} B/ \;
```

The basic syntax breaks down like this:

- `find A/ -type f`: `find` items in the directory `A/` whose type is a file (instead of a directory)…
- `-maxdepth 1 -name '.*'`: To this for a `maxdepth` of 1 directories and whose `name` begins with `.`.
- `-exec cp -p {} B/ \;`: And once these files are found, `exec` the `cp` command with a `-p` flag to preserve dates/times from the source (`{}`) to the destination of `B/`.

I like using `maxdepth` to add a layer of control so I am not accidentally copying a whole filesystem. But feel free to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for item in `find A -type d | grep -E "\."` ; do cp -r $item B ; done
```

- `find A -type d` provides a recursive list within A with only directories
- `grep -E "\."` filters directories with a dot (i.e.: hidden directories)
- the -E option was needed here because without it it means "current directory" as well
- the backslash is to avoid the meaning, under regexp, of "any character"
- `cp -r` to copy recursively

I have created the files and folders structure for A and executed the command in Git Bash (I'm not with a linux just right now) and it worked.

Comment: This breaks if files have whitespace or special characters in their name or path.

Comment: Thanks for noticing :) Actually I limitied to the "test case" by @gaboroncancio. If you can give me other test battery I may try to improve that (of course if you want, improve it by yourself either editing this response or creating a new answer)

Comment: You could simply put the dotfiles in a folder called `A B`, and then it'd act unexpectedly because it'd expand to `cp -r A B/.dotfile B`. The general advice is [not to parse `find` or `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) at all. If you use `find` you should also use its own options for filtering rather than `grep`, and if you pipe `find` output somewhere else, use `-print0`, or directly call the command you want. See the [`find`  manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files).

Comment: Even more generally, when working with files it's safest to use shell globs as explained in other answers (although they often require `extglob` to be set).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Let's leave the `find` parsing then.

Comment: Even aside from the badness of parsing the output of `find`, (1) This works for the _example_ file and directory names given in the question, but this answer will include any name that ***contains*** a dot (e.g., `somefile.c`), i.e., treating it as a hidden file. (2) Speaking of files, the question says “hidden files and hidden subdirectories” – so why are you saying `-type d`? (3) Why are you giving `grep` the `-E` option? I tried it and got the same results with and without it.

Comment: (1) yes, you're right. maybe using ^\..* for grep would work better (2) As the desired output included `B/.b/somefile` I supposed that @gaboroncancio wanted every file (hidden or not) that was inside a hidden directory.(3) without the -E option my grep includes A directory itself (ymmv, i worked with git bash)

Comment: (1) You rarely need `.*` in regexs for `grep` unless it’s between two things, as in `foo.*bar`. Your suggestion of `^\.` is a good start, but consider: `find`’s output will look like `A`, `A/a`, `A/b`, `A/.a`, `A/.b`, … – so you might want to use `/\.`. (2) My point was that the question shows an example file of `A/.a`, and that your command would miss that (because the `-type d` would filter out the plain file `A/.a`, and the grep would filter out the `A`). But it occurs to me that, if you deleted the `-type` flag, you could end up copying the `A/.b` directory ***and*** the `A/.b/.c` file.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use this other command if the second character is alphanumeric ([source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-do-you-copy-hidden-files-from-one-directory-to-another-387107/)):

```
cp -r A/.[a-zA-Z0-9]* B
```

Comment: This works for the _example_ file and directory names given in the question, but the text of the question says “hidden files and hidden subdirectories (the ones starting with a dot)”, and this answer will not find files and directories whose names begin with a dot and a special character; e.g., `.@foo` or `..c`.

Comment: That is why I point that it works if the second character is alphanumeric. ;)